# How to extract balance from bitcoin address

Tags: php

I'm trying to extract the balance from a list of bitcoin addresses in a text file.

Here is my code:

```
<?php


$list = file("list.txt");
$file = "checked_list.txt";
foreach ($list as $address) {

    $url = "https://blockchain.info/address/" . $address . "?format=json";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    $FinalBalance = $json["final_balance"];
    echo $address . " Balance is: " . $FinalBalance;
    $data_array = array($address, $FinalBalance);
    //Saving to file
    $my_data = file_put_contents($file, implode(' ', $data_array) . "\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    sleep(5);
}
```

My issue here is when I have more than 1 line in list.txt it will throw an error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://blockchain.info/address/ADDRESS-HERE
?format=json): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
 in C:\laragon\www\Scanner\BalanceCheckerByAddress\check.php on line 9

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null
```

If it is only 1 single address, it will display the balance and save the data to checked_list.txt

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line right after `foreach`:

```
$address = trim($address);
```

Your problem is in function `file(..)` because every line in the file `list.txt` containts line break. And you should remove the white space before working the string `$address`.

Your full code should looks like this:

```
<?php

$list = file("list.txt");
$file = "checked_list.txt";

foreach ($list as $address) {

    $address = trim($address); // Added line to remove white-space

    $url = "https://blockchain.info/address/" . $address . "?format=json";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    $FinalBalance = $json["final_balance"];

    echo $address . " Balance is: " . $FinalBalance;
    echo "<br>"; // Added line for seeing the results better in web-browser

    $data_array = array($address, $FinalBalance);

    //Saving to file
    $my_data = file_put_contents($file, implode(' ', $data_array) . "\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

    sleep(5);
}
```

I tested the code in PHP 7.4.10 and it works well.